# How can I automatically plot graphs in R with ggplot and save them to a folder?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, automation, save

I'm trying to create a graph (using quickplot) for each column of a data set and save it to a folder as a pdf -any advice would be much appreciated!

So far I've made a test data frame (before I try it with 500+ columns)

```
test.data <-cbind.data.frame(data$col_1,data$col_2,data$col_3)
```

Then I've tried to write a function to plot and save the graphs. I'm trying to make the graphs bar charts (with some title & color specifications) which show the count of the no. people in each category. So the columns typically consist of categorical data.

```
plot.graphs <- function(x) {      
  for(i in colSums(x)){
    plots <- quickplot(i) +
      geom_bar(color= "#6267c1", fill="#6267c1") +
      labs(title= "i",
           x="i",
           y="Count") +
      theme(help()
        plot.title = element_text(colour = "#453694"),
        axis.title = element_text(colour ="#453694"))
    ggsave(plots,filename = "testplot",nm[1],".pdf",sep="")
    print(plots)
  }
}
plot.graphs(test.data)
```

However, this seems to come up with lots of errors so I don't think I'm doing it right.

Comment: `for(i in colSums()`  `colSums` is a function and where is the closing bracket for `for`?  Where is `i` being used inside the function? Another problem may be that your input data is `matrix` (using `cbind`) instead of `data.frame` i.e. `test.data <- data[c("col_1", "col_2", "col_3")]`

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll give those changes a try!

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your plot-code with a `pdf()` graphical device and `dev.off()`. `pdf()` will open a pdf graphical device, and store all graphics you generate in a file, until you close the graphical device with `dev.off()`.

I can't test your code because I don't have the dataset, but try this:

```
pdf(file = 'test.pdf', onefile = TRUE, paper = 'special', height = 11, width = 8.5)

for(i in colSums(x)){
    plots <- quickplot(i) +
      geom_bar(color= "#6267c1", fill="#6267c1") +
      labs(title= "i",
           x="i",
           y="Count") +
      theme(help()
        plot.title = element_text(colour = "#453694"),
        axis.title = element_text(colour ="#453694"))
}

dev.off()
```

Also see: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/pdf.html

Comment: Thanks so much for that! I'll give this a go :)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this is helpful for anyone, the following script ended up working for me:

```
plot.auto <- function(data, list = as.list(colnames(data))){
      df <- data
      ln <- length(names(data))
      for(i in 1:ln){

      plot <- quickplot(na.omit(df[,i],main=names(df)[i])) +
          geom_bar() +
          labs(title= colnames((df[,i])),
               x=colnames((df)[i]),
               y="y axis title") +
# this makes the titles and text particular colours 
          theme(
            plot.title = element_text(colour = "#455876"),
            axis.title = element_text(colour ="#455467"),
# this puts the labels on an angle so they don't overlap
            axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, hjust = 1))+
# this makes the title of the plot the same as the column name
          ggtitle(colnames((df)[i])) +
          geom_text(stat='count',aes(label=..count..),vjust=-0.3)

        print(length(unique(df[,i])))
# this deletes any characters in the column names which will make saving 
difficult        
        save_name1<- gsub("/","or",as.character(colnames(df)[i]))
        save_name<- gsub("\\?","",save_name1)

#this tells you each title of the graph as the function runs       
        print(save_name)

#this saves each graph in a folder which must be in your Working Directory 
eg. Auto_Plot_Folder (as a pdf) with the file the same as the column name

        ggsave(plot,filename = 
paste("Auto_Plot_folder/",save_name,".pdf",sep =""),device ="pdf")

      }
    }
```